# Error with check IMEI address and String

Tags: android, device, imei

I try to comparing the IMEI code and a string

```
public static String getDeviceIMEI(Context context) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    }
    String identifier = null;
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (tm != null)
        identifier = tm.getDeviceId();
    if (identifier == null || identifier.length() == 0)
        identifier = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    return identifier;
}
```

this method calculate the IMEI code of the device, it return a String with the code.
And this method compare the 2 string:

```
private boolean checkIMEI() {        
    if (Device.getDeviceIMEI(SplashScreenActivity.this) == "xxx")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

("xxx" is the personal IMEI address of my device)

But when I run it on the device, the method checkIMEI() returns to me false...
I don't have any kind of idea to solve the problem.
Thanks for helping

Comment: in `checkIMEI()` what is the value of `Device.getDeviceIMEI(SplashScreenActivity.this)` ? (can you log it). Also, if you didn't know, that `if` block is a little weird, it doesn't contain any code within it.

Comment: @Matthias, I log it and the value of the IMEI (from Device.getDeviceIMEI(...)) is the same value of my input ("xxx"), the xxx value is the result of Log.i("IMEI", Device.getDeviceIMEI(...));

Comment: oh right, if memory serves, in Java to compare strings you must use `String.equals(otherString)` not `==`

Comment: @Matthias ok, it works ! great, thank you

Comment: excellent, feel free to accept my answer as the correct one then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `==` to compare strings in Java which checks to see if it is the same object, not the same string of characters, you can use `.equals()` for that, like so:

```
private boolean checkIMEI() {        
    if (Device.getDeviceIMEI(SplashScreenActivity.this).equals("xxx"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getIMEI(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, one should always add an explanation to it.